# running a shoutcast radio in a chrome extension

Tags: background

i want to create a chrome extension for my internet shoutcast internet radio station.

i managed to make it all work, except that whenever i click away from the popup, it closes, and the stream stops with it.

after reading a little i saw that i need to create a background page, that will make the player run in the background.

thats where i got lost and confused.

how do i make the stream keep working even if i dont have the popup open?

again - heres how it goes:
when you click on the extension it opens, and my player shows up (a flash player in an iframe). i click Play and it works perfectly. when i wanna keep surfing the web, i click on the page im in and it closes the extension and stops the music.

**here are my files**
manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "JointRadio",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Online Radio Station",
  "background_page": "background.js",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["tabs"],
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }

      #mainplayer {

      }
    </style>

    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="popup.js">
  </head>
  <body>
  <iframe width="460" border=0 height="130" src="http://jointil.com/broadcast/flexAmp.swf" frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 id="mainplayer"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!! :)
adam

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make the stream play even if the popup is closed, but the problem is that the player doesn't display in the popup...
I added this code in "background.js"

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://85.25.118.16:7502/;');
audioElement.setAttribute('controls', true);
audioElement.setAttribute('hidden', false);
audioElement.play();
```

2 - manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Kombat Syndicate Radio Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Kombat Syndicate Radio",
"background": {
"persistent": true,
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action":   {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "19": "icons/icon.png",  
     "128": "icons/icon_128.png",
    "default_popup": "ksradio.html"
},

    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "background"]

    }
```

If I find out how to display the player in the popup I'll tell you.. And if you find how to display it before me, then please tell me :P

#### Edit:

I noticed that in your "popup.html" the "`<script src="popup.js">`" isn't correct, add "`</script>`" after "`<script src="popup.js">`" so you'll have "`<script src="popup.js"></script>`"

Comment: Thanks man, i copied your code to my files, changes the parameters to mine and when i click on the icon it starts the music, and even tho the player shows, its not really playing, cause the act of pressing the icon started the shoutcast stream.. you feel me? im gonna work on it now, just wanted to say thanks for giving me another hint.. if ill find out more im gonna put it here!

Comment: hi, the "audioElement.play();" attribute make the radio play just by refreshing the extension.. cant we just create 2 buttons "play" and "pause"? how do you do that?

Comment: Take a look at this: [link](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/)

And look in the source code of this page: [link](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/audiotag/)

I tried to make it work but it didn't work.. Maybe you'll find how :P if so let me know :D