# Google chrome extension popup: Keeping the popup running even when it's closed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

So I made my first extension (a shoutcast radio), it works fine, but I have a problem with it:

- The stream stops playing when the popup gets closed.

Basically my problem is the same as in this post ->[running a shoutcast radio in a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858238/running-a-shoutcast-radio-in-a-chrome-extension/)

---

#### So what I need help for is:

- Keeping the music playing even when the popup is closed.

---

#### The code:

1 - manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Kombat Syndicate Radio Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Kombat Syndicate Radio",
"browser_action":   {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "19": "icons/icon.png",  
     "128": "icons/icon_128.png",
    "default_popup": "ksradio.html"
},

    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"]

    }
```

2 - ksradio.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1><img style="margin-top:-15px;-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit- gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(87%, transparent),  to(white));
" src="icons/ks_radio_icon.png" /><br />Kombat Syndicate Radio</h1>

<div align="center" text-align="center" id="content">

<div id="smallffmp3">

<audio controls src="http://85.25.118.16:7502/;"></audio>

</div>

<a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls" target="_blank"><img  src="icons/VLC_48.png" title="VLC Media Player"/></a>

<a href="#" id="wmppop"><img src="icons/WMP_48.png" /></a>

<a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls" target="_blank"><img   src="icons/WinAmp_48.png" title="WinAmp Media Player" /></a>

<a href="http://85.25.118.16:7502/listen.pls" target="_blank"><img  src="icons/iTunes_48.png" title="iTunes" /></a>

<iframe align="middle" style="display:block;" name="infos"   src="http://phpks.comoj.com/radioinfos.php" width="65%" height="70%" frameborder="0"   scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S: I have to mention that I'm not really good with javascript :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the logic and player to the background page.

Comment: @RobW
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: What code are you using? You mentioned that you're not quite good with JavaScript, by the way. What does that mean? Are you just hacking around in an attempt to get something to work without any knowledge, or do you already understand the basics of JavaScript? How about Chrome extensions: Are you familiar with the basic concepts and the API?

Comment: I know the basics of javascript, but since I'm new to chrome extensions I don't know about the API.
What I did in the code, was that I created a  "background.js", put in it `document.write('<audio controls src="http://85.25.118.16:7502/;"></audio>');`

And in the ksradio.html I did: `<script>
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
</script>` in a div where the player is supposed to be.

And in manifest.json I added:
`   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },`

this is probably wrong since it's not working lol

Comment: Read about background pages at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html, and also read the docs about the CSP: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Comment: I read that already, but still can't figure out what to do..

Comment: If you have really gone through docs it would have solved your problem :) ... using document.write in background.js can not solve your problem..

Comment: @Sudarshan
I really went through the docs many times lol but still can't figure out what to do. But somehow I managed to make the stream play even when the popup is closed, but.. The player doesn't show up and the music starts playing as soon as the extension is loaded...

background.js:
`var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://85.25.118.16:7502/;');
audioElement.setAttribute('controls', true);
audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', false);
audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();`

Comment: @NexsHax: Background page execution time starts after extension is loaded, this causes music being played as soon as extension is loaded.

Comment: And the fix would be...?

Comment: @NexsHax: Use message communication from popup to background page to indicate running of music, so it will play only when popup is clicked..

Comment: You can find your answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540599/chrome-extension-keep-popup-loaded/27894017#27894017