# Chrome Extension keep popup loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a extension for some internet radio station. Currently its opening new window to play music, but I want to make an extension.

I created popup and put the URL of internet radio station inside it as an iframe. The problem is, when the popup closes, the iframe also closes and music stops, which is kinda sad.

Any ideas on how to keep the content of popup loaded even while it is "closed" ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be the expected functionality?  You just want to insert music into a website without giving the user a way to stop it after they close the popup?

Comment: If you want a persistent connection in an extension, look into background scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Set the manifest to have

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
```

Then you can load the script this way once you execute the page popup the script will run.

If you do this i would suggest adding key commands to stop,pause and play the command like so to your manifest.

```
 "commands": {
      "commands": {
      "Play": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
          "mac": "Command+Shift+U"
        },
        "description": "Toggle feature foo"
      },
      "Stop": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Z",
          "mac": "Command+Shift+D"
        },
        "description": "Toggle feature foo"
      }
  }
```

Then in your background file that you set in the manifest add a chrome listener

```
 chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    console.log('Command:', command);
    if(command == "Play"){
        //play function here
    }else if(command == "Stop"){
        //stop function here
    }
 });
```

Comment: This does not answer the essential part of the question (keeping an `iframe` alive). Please expand your example. Also, while your advice is solid, but uncalled for and takes up 80% of your answer.

Comment: Well to expand the iframe could and should hide all visual cues and make the default body transparent so in essence you could size it on click to 1px by 1px if you want

Comment: making it hidden but still the audio will play