# Browser extension popup kept loaded

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, browser, popup, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am looking to keep the browser extension pop-up loaded so that when you try to open it, the contents of it do not have to load every time.

I am currently specifying my pop-up through browser action in manifest.json like so:

```
"browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      }
```

I found this answer from 8 years ago [Chrome Extension keep popup loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540599/chrome-extension-keep-popup-loaded), but the method it outlines, making the window 1 px high and expanding it back when pressed seems unideal. Is there a better built-in way to do so?

I am specifically trying to write an extension for firefox, and thus cannot use manifest v3 features as well, although I am not sure how much that matters.

Comment: The browser_action popup cannot be kept open. You can only use a DOM element in the web page such as an iframe to display the popup or do the work in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm hm, then is there any particular way you would recommend creating a DOM element that would be persistent across webpages?  Maybe I could move on from there and figure out a way to hide it and show it? There are some obvious ones like just popping open a new window with the HTML file but other than that I am not that experienced to come up with a better suited solution?

Comment: It will be a part of the page so its persistence is limited to the page until it navigates.